# Error message: Uncaught TypeError: items.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript

I need to add buttons to the existing li. Here is my code:

function buttonDelete() {

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var button =document.createElement("button");
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
items.appendChild(button);
button.onclick = function() {
this.remove();
items.remove();
}
}
buttonDelete();
```

However, I receive an error: Uncaught TypeError: items.appendChild is not a function.

If I select only one li item (var items = document.querySelector("li");), it adds button only for the first item.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of items... not a single item

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName` *function* returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name, as a *NodeList* object.

You should define a `loop` and append `button` child, for every item from returned *collection*.

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
Array.from(items).forEach(elem => {
  var button =document.createElement("button");
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
  button.onclick = function() {
      this.parentElement.remove();
  }
  elem.appendChild(button);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! :)

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of li's. You need to loop through each if you wish to add a button to each of them.

```js
const items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
Object.values(items).forEach((li,i)=>{
   const but = document.createElement("button");
   but.innerHTML = i;
   li.appendChild(but);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```